# How can I workaround this android TextWatcher restriction?

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextWatcher` defined on an `EditText` field. Within the `TextWatcher.onTextChanged()` method, I sometimes reset the `EditText` value to an empty string. When I do I get

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (2 ... 3) ends beyond length 0
    at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:934)
```

Can anybody suggest a workaround to safely clear down the EditText from within a TextWatcher.

My code is ...

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence chars, int start, int before,int count) {
        // if user keys Enter, process the contents and clear down the EditText
        if (chars.toString().indexOf("\n") > -1) {
            processChars(s.toString().replace("\n", ""));
            editTextField.setText("");
        }
    } 
};

editTextField.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: have u tried putting those codes in afterTextChanged() method?

Comment: see the docs of onTextChanged:  "It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from this callback"

Comment: Try `editTextField.removeTextChangedListener(tw)` before clearing the `EditText`

Comment: @shoerat its an error to change s from this callback,  see my comment above

Comment: @pskink, handler would not be helpful?

Comment: @shoerat,  could be,  could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @Michael Shrestha, @pskink and @shoe rat for illuminating the way. The Solution I went with was Michael's suggestion to move the code from onTextChanged() to afterTextChanged()

Answer (score 1):

As [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/) has mentioned in the comments, "***It is an error to attempt to make changes to s from [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html#onTextChanged%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) callback***". So, instead of changing the `EditText` value directly, use `Handler`. An example is provided below for reference.

```
private EditText mEditText;
private TextWatcher mTextWatcher;

private static final int MSG_ADD_TEXTWATCHER = 100;
private static final int MSG_PROCESS_CHARS = 200;
private static final int MSG_REMOVE_TEXTWATCHER = 300;

private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);
private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    private final WeakReference<MainActivity> myActivity;

    public MyHandler(MainActivity activity) {
        myActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        MainActivity activity = myActivity.get();
        if (activity != null) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_ADD_TEXTWATCHER:
                    activity.addTextWatcher();
                    break;
                case MSG_PROCESS_CHARS:
                    activity.processChars(msg.obj.toString());
                    break;
                case MSG_REMOVE_TEXTWATCHER:
                    activity.removeTextWatcher();
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}

...

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    if (s.toString().indexOf("\n") > -1) {
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.what = MSG_PROCESS_CHARS;
        msg.obj = s.toString().replace("\n", "");
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}

...

private void addTextWatcher() {
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
}

private void removeTextWatcher() {
    mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(mTextWatcher);
    mEditText.setText("");
}

private void processChars(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_REMOVE_TEXTWATCHER);
}
```

You need to call `mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MSG_ADD_TEXTWATCHER);` where/whenever appropriate according to your project requirements.